# See when AuraDefinitionBundle was last updated?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, tooling-api

I know we can Query [AuraDefinitionBundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_auradefinitionbundle.htm) with the tooling api and retrieve some fields, but one that is not included is Last Modified Date. How would one retrieve that information for all AuraDefinitionBundle records? I am documenting all of our AuraDefinitionBundle records and that would be really nice to have to see when it was last modified and pull that info into a CSV file. Any insight would be helpful!

Comment: Should you not base such info on your version control system's information?

Comment: if we had one i likely would be and wouldn't be doing this project. Not my call

Comment: Ouch! That's a project waiting for disaster then...

Comment: tell me about it, i jumped on the project a few months ago and have been dealing with the ramifications of not having one since

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this field when you query through the Tooling API

```
/services/data/v49.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+id,LastModifiedDate+FROM+AuraDefinitionBundle
```

[image]

You can also just use SOQL to get the same [Last Modified Date field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_AuraDefinitionBundle.htm).

```
SELECT Id,LastModifiedDate,DeveloperName FROM AuraDefinitionBundle
```

[image]

Another option is to use specific ID of an AuraDefinitionBundle through the Tooling API as well

```
/services/data/v48.0/tooling/sobjects/AuraDefinitionBundle/Id here
```

[image]